# Windows Octave fails to paste text from clipboard?

Tags: windows, octave

I am just install Octave 4.2.0 in Windows 10 and try to do some Machine Learning exercises.  I notice that I can't paste the normal clipboard content to the Octave.

Does anyone else have this issue?  If so, any work around?   Or is it just bug in the program?

Comment: Likely just a bug.  I tried later, it worked about 50% of time.   Sometimes ctrl-v worked.  Sometimes, it failed and the right mouse click would work.

Comment: have never had any issues with 4.2.0 on Windows 7. Would recommend filing a bug report over at http://bugs.octave.org , especially if you can reliably recreate this issue so others can try on their platforms.

Comment: Aren't you able to past into very window(for example the commandline, the integrated scintilla editor and so on) of the GNU Octave GUI or are you using the CLI? Do you use CTRL+v or right click context menu "insert"? Which keyboard layout und language setting?

Comment: [Related bug](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?39305) (still occurring with version 4.4.2). Restarting Octave helps.

Comment: For me (windows 10 64bit), with Octave 4.2.2, neither ctrl-v nor right-click-and-paste works. I could confirm that ctrl-c in the editor does copy the selected text to the clipboard (because I could paste it to somewhere rather than the Octave editor).

Comment: does not work for me too.

Comment: It would be useful to know if anyone still has this issue with recent Octave updates (5.2.1 as of this comment).  there have been significant GUI bug fixes since then.

Answer (score 1):

Run >> preferences, and in the Shortcuts tab, untick the option at the top "Disable global shortcuts when Command Window has focus". (I don't know since what version it is there.)

If you disable global shortcuts, Ctrl-V (for paste) is disabled because it is a Windows thing.

If you do not disable them, Ctrl-V will work. So will Ctrl-C to copy text, but it will also still work to abort an execution.

Answer (score 0):

Although your description doesn't indicate the exact place you're trying to paste contents into, there were a couple bugs around the time of Octave 4.2 specifically related to this problem.  See:

[bug #51095: editor doesnt allow paste of exisiting clipboard data](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?51095)

and

[bug #52361: Ctrl-C/Ctrl-V only works reliably if executed as very first action](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?52361)

both bugs have since been patched and closed (around version 4.4), and reports seem to indicate that the problem has not resurfaced in later versions. Anyone experiencing similar issues in a recent version of Octave (v5.2.1 as of today) should either comment on one of those closed bug reports or create a new one at https://bugs.octave.org

Answer (score -2):

If you click on the icon in the title bar on the top left corner of the 
window, you'll get an edit option, and you can choose to mark (choose 
the text to copy), copy, and paste from there.

Comment: On Windows the window icon shows nothing but the window menu (move, resize, max, min,...)